# How to dynamically get href links and add them to an HTML element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint Designer and the HTML is generated automatically. The way it works now is that only the  tag is clickable and the div around it is not.

```
<ul class="dfwp-list">
  <li>
    <div class="item" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/accounting/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/file-invoice-dollar.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/accounting/Pages/default.aspx" title="Accounting Division">Accounting
          Division</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/air/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image" src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/wind.svg"
            title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/air/Pages/default.aspx" title="Air Quality Program">Air Quality
          Program</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/aviation/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/plane-departure.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/aviation/Pages/default.aspx" title="Aviation Department">Aviation
          Department</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/healthcare/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/building.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/healthcare/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="Broward Addiction &amp; Recovery Center">Broward Addiction &amp; Recovery Center</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/budget"><img class="image" src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/money-bill-alt.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/budget" title="Budget &amp; Management">Budget &amp; Management</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/callcenter/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image" src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/phone.svg"
            title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/callcenter/Pages/default.aspx" title="Call Center">Call Center</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/construction/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/toolbox.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/construction/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="Construction Management Division">Construction Management Division</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/administrator/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/folder-open.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/administrator/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="County Administrator's Office">County Administrator's Office</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/econdev/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/chart-area.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/econdev/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="Economic &amp; Small Business Dev.">Economic &amp; Small Business Dev.</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/eldervets/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/handshake.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/eldervets/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="Elderly &amp; Veteran's Services Division">Elderly &amp; Veteran's Services Division</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/EmergencyManagement/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image"
            src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/ambulance.svg" title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/EmergencyManagement/Pages/default.aspx"
          title="Emergency Management">Emergency Management</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="image-area-left">
        <a href="/Agencies/EAP/Pages/default.aspx"><img class="image" src="/Agencies/PublishingImages/user.svg"
            title=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="link-item"><a href="/Agencies/EAP/Pages/default.aspx" title="Employee Assistance Program">Employee
          Assistance Program</a>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am creating a code that gets the href of the clicked element and directs the user to the page on click. But what happens is that when I click it sends me to the same page instead of the url that belongs to the clicked event.

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
$(".item").click(function(event) {
    var href = $('.item a').attr('href');
    window.location = href;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Instead of `var href = $('.item a').attr('href');`, try `var href = $('.item div a').attr('href');`

Comment: @RobMoll thanks for your answer; I tried your code but all the links clicked go to the same url

Comment: Also change `window.location = href;` to `window.location.href = href`

Comment: ...and put `event.preventDefault();` as the first line inside the function - like this: `$(".item").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();                                                                               
            var href = $('.item a').attr('href');
            window.location = href;            
        });`

Comment: @RobMoll still getting the same result. When I click it goes to the same url which is the first item of the list

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the entire contents of the <ul> tag which contains the <li> elements?

Comment: The selector you are using for getting the href is prone to grabbing the first tag that matches the class (".item a") if you update that selector to grab instead $(this).children(".link-item") you will grab the appropriate link.

Comment: @RobMoll I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".item").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
});
$(".item").click(function(event) {
    var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    window.location = href;
    event.preventDefault();
});
```